# Writing an open letter to say how much I want to work at a specific company

Tags: applications, education

I am a junior in high school, and I dream of working at a specific company after college. I want to write an essay about why and how I want to get to work there, what I'm doing in order for it to happen, etc. I'd then like to post it online to slightly increase my chances of getting admitted, as they'll see my early (or maybe not as early) interest in their particular company when I apply to work for them.

Could you please give me some advice on how it should be done? Where exactly should I put it, so that it will be a legitimate source, and what should I specifically include in it? Should I write about my academic achievements, such as olympiad successes?

Comment: 1. this will NOT increase your chances, as this will be "lost" by the time you apply to work for them. 2. you should absolutely NOT be showing your dedication to a company by getting random people on the internet to express said dedication for you. 3. have a read of the "joke" CVs that bankers get, and keep that in mind

Comment: by example, never do this - http://gawker.com/5883684/the-awful-cover-letter-all-of-wall-street-is-laughing-about

Comment: @bharal surely won't do that thing!

Comment: They'll see this too..

Answer (score 9):

Firstly, I'd like to say that it's great that you know what you want to do and that you're willing to start talking publicly about what you want from your career, so well done on that and keep it up.

That said, I do not think that writing an essay specifically saying how much you want to work at a given company is the best option. That is, after all, what your cover letter is for, and a full essay published on a public forum could look a bit desperate, to be honest.
(If you are absolutely set on this, a blog or LinkedIn post, and services such as [Medium](https://medium.com/) which allow you to write longer essays for your profile may be appropriate.)

Instead of an essay specifically about them, I'd recommend something like an in-depth LinkedIn profile geared towards them. There, you can expand on your academic achievements and other successes, and use the summary, skills and causes to expand upon your future career wishes (e.g. the aspects of working at Goldman Sachs that appeal to you) to say what you want from your professional life.

LinkedIn is a good option as it will appear among the top results for individuals on Google and has a format ready to go for you to fill in. In order to then expand upon your online professional presence, you could start to build a personal website, for example. Since you are already conscious of what you want to do to draw attention to your skills, you are in a good place to start looking into professional personal branding - there are many online resources that can tell you more and advise on this.

A final note about the essay - I'd be wary of mentioning any particular company too much in all of this. The reason for this is that it's great that you know what you want to do, but life is pretty messy, and you might (for example) end up doing an internship in a smaller company that you fall in love with. Branding yourself for one specific company could close off other opportunities with other companies that will expand your experience, and this may make you seem a bit naive. Don't close yourself off quite yet!

Comment: man, he lobbed it at you, and you caught it, pondered on it, and gave really good advice back. this is a lovely answer, good job.

Comment: @Luna Thank you! I really appreciate your insightful advice!

Comment: I would like to second the idea that you shouldn't point yourself at one company to the exclusion of all others. I would identify what it is about that company that makes it so appealing and target your job search on those qualities instead of the specific company. There are companies you've never heard of that might be an even better fit for you than the one you're dreaming about.